# Is there a way to take x where?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

What I'm trying to do is take 5 where **bool** is *true* and take 5 where **bool** is *false* and sort them desc on **bool**

```
|# | Name  | Bool  |
|01| Test1 | true  |
|02| Test2 | false |
|03| Test3 | true  |
|04| Test4 | true  |
|xx| etc...
```

Instead of doing this:

```php
$boolTrue  = Test::where('bool', true)->get();
$boolFalse = Test::where('bool', false)->get();
return $boolFalse->merge($boolTrue)->sortByDesc('bool');
```

I would like to make just one request to the database instead of 2 and would like to know if
something like this is possible:

```php
// Obviously doesn't work
Test::where('bool', true)->take(5)->where('bool', false)->take(5)->orderBy('bool');
```

Comment: Do you mean [unions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions)?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden YES! This will answer my question! Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Ron van der Heijden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293244/ron-van-der-heijden) replied to me on my question. I should use [unions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions).

What I did:

```php
$boolTrue = Test::where('bool', true);
return Test::where('bool', false)->union($boolTrue)->orderByDesc('bool')->get();
```

This will only fire 1 query! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below.

```
$true = Test::where('bool', true); //Model instance
$false = Test::where('bool', false)->union($true); //Second model instance

$groupby = DB::query()->fromSub($false, 'nq')
->orderBy('bool')
->get();
```